# What variables do I keep in the model? multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression

What do I do when none of the predictor variables are significant? All the p-values are greater than the significance level of 0.05.

Comment: you might want to expand your questions to include (1) number of predictors examined (2) method of examining predictors (feature selection) (3) number of observations (4) motivation behind building model

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what question you are trying to answer with you regression analysis.  It may also depend on what tests you have looked at and which you have not.

Did you look at the p-value associated with the overall F-test?  It can be significant while all the individual adjusted p-values are not.  This just indicates redundancy in your choice of predictor variables, but suggests that they (or a subset of them) still predict the outcome.

If the overall test is not significant then that mean that you have not found any relationship (at least following the assumptions of the regression) between the potential predictors and the response variable.  This could be because you do not have enough data (in which case you can use what you learned this time to design a more powerful study) or it could mean that there is no relationship and it is time to move on to other avenues of research.  Examining the confidence intervals (and diagnostic plots, etc.) along with knowledge of the science behind your data can help you decide if there is a potential worth pursuing.